# How can I click on the children element in the selected element in the cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have table with rows (list). I get the element using get and click on it.
HTML:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr data-row-key="5fc63ee4502a5d60c8fc9550">
            <td>43</td>
            <td>testName12</td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <button type="button">
                    <i aria-label="icon: edit" class="anticon-edit"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button">
                    <i aria-label="icon: delete" class="anticon-delete"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This line is selected for me, everything is fine:

```
cy.get("tr:contains('testName12')", { timeout:20000}).click({force: true})
```

But in this element I have the same children ('button') and I need to click on one of them:

```
cy.get("tr:contains('testName12')", { timeout:20000}).children('.anticon-delete').click({force: true})
```

I get an error:

```
Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: .anticon-delete, but never found it. Queried from element: <tr.ant-table-row.ant-table-row-level-0>
```

How can I click on the children element in the selected element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative would be to use [find()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find.html#Syntax)

```
cy.get("tr:contains('testName12')", { timeout:20000}).find('.anticon-delete').click({force: true})
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your approach, I would suggest the following changes using [parents](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/parents.html#Syntax)

```
cy.contains('td', 'testName12')
    .parents('tr')
    .children('.anticon-delete')
    .click({force: true})
```

Edit: If the parents approach doesn`t work I would try using [within](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within.html)

```
cy.get("tr:contains('testName12')", { timeout:20000})
    .within(()=>{
        cy.get('.anticon-delete').click({force: true})
    })
```

Comment: There is error: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: .anticon-delete, but never found it. Queried from element: <tr.ant-table-row.ant-table-row-level-0> in the     .children('.anticon-delete')